# Default value for user role - Spring security

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-security

I'm trying to add a default role value when the user register in Spring Security.

I have two models "User" and "Role" linked with a many-to-many relation.

User.java

```
@NotEmpty
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
```

Role.java

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
@Column(length=15, unique=true, nullable=false)
private String role = RoleType.USER.getRole();
```

data.sql

```
INSERT INTO ROLE(role) VALUES ('USER');
INSERT INTO USER(email,password) VALUES ('user@mail.com','user');
INSERT INTO USER_ROLES(user_id, roles_id) VALUES (1,1);
```

The idea here is to use the role_id to set the user role, but i would prefer use a String for lisibility. Something like this in one or two lines

```
INSERT INTO USER_ROLES(user_id, roles) VALUES (1, "ADMIN");
INSERT INTO USER_ROLES(user_id, roles) VALUES (1, "DBA");
```

Also when I'm trying to create a user from JAVA I need to use the role dao in order to retrieve the corresponding id and I would like to set a new user to "ROLE_USER" by default.

UserDBTest.java

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    User user = new User();
    user.setEmail("email@mail.com");
    user.setPassword("password");
    user.addRole(roleRepository.findOne(1L)); //detached entity passed to persist
    user = userRepository.save(user);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the SQL like this:

```sql
INSERT INTO USER_ROLES(user_id, roles)
  VALUES (1, (SELECT id FROM roles WHERE role='ADMIN'));
```

The JPA error you are experiencing is because you don't run in a transaction. *For example,* if you use TestNG you can let your test class extend `AbstractTransactionalTestNGSpringContextTests`, and it will work.

**Update:** If the extra database lookup is a concern, an option would be to store the role name directly in `USER_ROLES` table, User.java would then look like:

```java
@ElementCollection
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Set<RoleType> roles;
```

Comment: It makes two queries for a simple thing, it sounds like a little heavy solution. I can use TestNG but the idea is that I want to simplify the process of creating user with a role in my Spring application.

Comment: @melkir That cost should be negligible, but I added an option in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store `Role` as a String, then you can represent it as enum in Java and drop the table altogether.
Then, you may represent the relationship as `@OneToMany` between `User` and `UserRole`.

In `UserRole.java`

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
User user;

@Column(name = "role")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING) // this tells JPA to store enum name in db
Role role; //role enum
```

Comment: Do you think that a OneToMany is more appropriety in my case ?
A user can have many role (or profile) and a role can belong to multiple users. So I don't really understand here why I would use a OneToMany relationship.
What are the benefits and the drawbacks by using one or either ?

Comment: Actually, the relationship is still many-to-many in a way, but because I dropped the Role table and store it as enum only, then there's no way to specify as many-to-many, because Role is not an entity anymore. But you achieve the same thing. Different roles can be assigned to different users, there's no foreign key there as now it's just the enum.

Anyway, the whole idea of a user having multiple roles is not very good as you may have conflicting permissions. But that's another story.